# How can I mimick OpenLDAP's slappasswd using NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptojs

My goal is to use NodeJS to create LDAP password hashes that are similar to what comes out of the `slappasswd` command-line tool.

Here's how LDAP passwords can be produced with command-line:

```
slappasswd -h '{SSHA}' -s 'P@ssw0rd'
{SSHA}1RHPt8m4AWLjK8Px1MT6FEBJOBJpdzqT
```

The result is a base64 encoded, salted SHA1 password.

Here's what I tried initially to recreate it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

import sha1 from 'crypto-js/sha1.js';

let password = 'P@ssW0rd';
let salt = btoa(0xA5);  // Not random, just a proof of concept temporary value.
let hash = sha1(password + salt);
console.log('{SSHA}' + btoa(hash));
```

But, I got a much longer string than what the `slappasswd` command produced and I'm not sure why.

```
{SSHA}NDVkN2JjODQ2ZDk3Yjc2YmViNTU3MzUzYjBiNzExN2ZmYzMxYWY5ZA==
```

I did some digging around on the net and found this on an LDAP password generator web page:

```
<script src="lib/cryptojs/core.js"></script>
<script src="lib/cryptojs/sha1.js"></script>
<script src="lib/cryptojs/enc-base64.js"></script>

<script>
    function slappasswd(password) {
      var salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8).toString().substr(0,4);
      var hash = CryptoJS.SHA1(password + salt);
      var base = CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse(hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1) + salt).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
      return '{SSHA}' + base;
    }
...
```

The web page produces a string that is the same length as what comes out of `slappasswd`, so I assume it's an accurate recreation of the `slappasswd` logic.

Using this information, my next attempt looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';

let password = 'P@ssW0rd';
let salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8).toString().substr(0,4);
let hash = sha1(password + salt);
let base = CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse(hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1) + salt).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
console.log('{SSHA}' + base);
```

However, I get errors.

First, there is `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'WordArray')`

If I replace `let salt =` with `let salt = btoa(0xA5)` from my first attempt code, I then get the error: `ReferenceError: sha1 is not defined`

My feeling is that I've got the import wrong somehow.

I'm trying to do the ES6 module equivalent of `var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");`, but failing somewhere.

So my question is two-fold:

1. Can my first attempt be made to produce a string length similar to what slappassword outputs?
2. If not, what can I do to fix the errors I'm getting in the second attempt?

Ideally, I'd like to understand where I went wrong in my first attempt rather than simply copying and pasting someone else's code (second attempt) without fully grasping it.

Comment: This is because salt is different than being used by these libraries. thats why it is a large string but it doesn't matter as long as your code folowing standards of sha1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is alternative of python/php implementations for NodeJS.

> Import Crypto module

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
```

> It will be used to create LDAP password hashes (SSHA)

```
function generate_hash(passwd, salt) {
  if (!salt) {
     const buf = crypto.randomBytes(4);
     salt = buf.toString('base64');
  }
  let ctx = crypto.createHash('sha1');
  ctx.update(passwd, 'utf-8');
  ctx.update(salt, 'binary');
  let digest = ctx.digest('binary');
  return '{SSHA}' + Buffer.from(digest + salt, 'binary').toString('base64');
}
```

> It will be used to verify hash

```
function verify_hash(passwd, hash) {
  let bhash = Buffer.from(hash.substr(6), 'base64');
  let salt = bhash.toString('binary', 20);
  let newssha = generate_hash(passwd, salt);
  return hash === newssha;
}
```

> Test it together

```
 const hash = generate_hash("qwe1234");
 let test = verify_hash("qwe1234", hash);
 console.log(test);  //Output: true
 let test = verify_hash("XXXX", hash);
 console.log(test);  //Output: false
```

Hope it help you. Please let me know.

[Try Now](https://onecompiler.com/nodejs/3yb4txh3f)